# How do you add objects to a javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

```
var Test = (function() {
    return {
        useSub: function () {
            this.Sub.sayHi();
        },

        init: function () {
            $(document).ready(this.useSub);
        }
    };
})();

Test.Sub = (function () {
    return {
        sayHi: function () {
            alert('hi');
        }
    };
})();

Test.useSub(); // works
Test.init(); // explodes
```

Above I am trying to create a Test namespace and add an object Sub to it. I was doing fine until I tried using the object in jQuery. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sayHi' of undefined". If there is a better way to do this, I am open to it.

Edit:

Obviously this was demo code. In my real application the solution that I went with because I think it is the most clear is this one:

```
var Namespace (function () {
  return {
    init: function () {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        Namespace.onReady();
      }
    },
    onReady: function() {
      alert('Now I am back in the Namespace scope. Proceed as planned');
    }
  };
})();
```

Edit2: All jQuery callbacks seem to require they are used in this manner or else the scoping is screwed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a scope problem. If you do

```
$(document).ready(this.useSub);
```

then `this.useSub` will be executed in the `window` scope (so inside the function, `this` refers to the `window` object) and there doesn't exist a `Sub` attribute.

Try:

```
init: function () {
    var obj = this;
    $(function(){obj.useSub()});
}
```

<del>For some reason it does not work using `$(document).ready(function(){obj.useSub()});` but it works with the `$()` shortcut.</del>

Comment: var that = this;

$(document).ready(function () {that.useSub();});

Works for me.

Comment: @Skilldrick: I tested it with JS Bin and it does not work there, but then it has probably to do with their setup.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
var Test = {
  useSub : function () { 
    Test.Sub.sayHi(); 
  }, 
  init: function () { 
    $(document).ready(Test.useSub); 
  },
  Sub: {
    sayHi: function () { 
      alert('hi'); 
    } 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in this line:

```
$(document).ready(this.useSub);
```

you're passing a reference to a function and the scope is lost- when the function runs, `this` no longer means `Test`.